# Can I use my own optionally namespaced HTML tags if I'm setting the CSS for each one?

Tags: html, css, custom-element, htmlelements

I'd like to my own HTML tags but I don't want new tags that might use the same name to cause them to break in the future.

Is this a good idea? Could I use a namespace to avoid conflicts?

---

#### Example:

HTML :

```
<b:HGroup>
    <span>item 1</span><span>item 2</span><span>item 3</span>
</b:HGroup>
```

CSS:

```
@namespace b "library://ns.example.com/framework/1";

b|HGroup {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I read a related question and it suggests DTD. I'd rather not create a DTD but if it's necessary, then I'd like to define it inline. Also, I'd like it to be run as HTML5, not XHTML.

---

#### Note:

I do NOT want to use `div` plus a `class`.

As far as I understand it, it looks like custom elements I've written will not be overwritten by future elements of the same name if I explicitly register my custom element. Here is a quote from the [W3](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#concepts):

> Because element registration can occur at any time, a non-custom
> element could be created that might in the future become a custom
> element after an appropriate definition is registered. Such elements
> are called undefined potentially-custom elements. If such a definition
> is ever registered, the element will be upgraded, becoming a custom
> element.

---

I've included a full page prototype based on the answers and I can't get it to attach any CSS to any element with a namespace. I've included some JS I found on one of the links but commented out part of it that was giving me errors. My main concern is getting elements with namespaces to be styled by the CSS with namespaces. From how I understand it that should work without JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2002/spark"
  xmlns:space="http://www.w3.org/2002/space"
  xmlns:spaced="http://www.w3.org/2002/spaced">
<head>

<script>
  "use strict";
 
  const inDocument = document.querySelector("example-element");
  const outOfDocument = document.createElement("example-element");
  // Before the element definition, both are HTMLElement:
  //console.assert(inDocument instanceof HTMLElement);
  //console.assert(outOfDocument instanceof HTMLElement);

  //class ExampleElement extends HTMLElement {};
  //customElements.define("example-element", HTMLElement);
  
  //class ExampleElement3 extends HTMLElement {}
  //customElements.define("element3", ExampleElement3);

  //document.body.appendChild(outOfDocument);
  
</script>
<style>

@namespace s url(http://www.w3.org/2000/spark);
@namespace space url(http://www.example.com/2000/spark-space);
@namespace spaced "http://www.example.com/2002/spark-spaced";

example-element {
    color: red;
    display:block;
}
element2 {
    color:green;
    font-weight:bold;
}
s|element3 {
    color:yellow;
}
space-element {
    color:yellow;
}
space|space-element {
    display:block;
    color:yellow;
}
spaced|spaced-element {
    display:block;
    color:yellow;
}
</style>
</head>

    <body>
        <example-element>example-element</example-element>
        <element2>element 2</element2>
        <space-element>space element</space-element>
        <s:element3>s namespace element 3</s:element3>
        <space:space-element>space namespace el</space:space-element>
        <spaced:spaced-element>spaced namespace el</spaced:spaced-element>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's allowed for all newer browsers. However if your not careful this could end up being a big mess. I would advice using the standard elements. Older browsers and other developers have a better way of understanding.

Comment: Have you thought about [Web Components](http://webcomponents.org/)? Seems like an overkill, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: I've added a full HTML page example and custom named element appears to be working but elements with namespaces are not working. CSS is not being applied. I've tried to avoid JS for now but I've included some JS from the links provided in the answers just in case it is really necessary. For me the JS generates parse errors on the `console` and `class` lines so I've commented them out. If possible I'd like to figure out and prioritize the namespace issues over the JS ones.

Comment: Update: It looks like I need to change `s|element` to `s\:element`. That's not how the spec says but it seems to be working in a very early initial test. Also odd, the CSS namespaces and the XMLNS in the HTML tag don't seem to matter. Only tested in webkit so far though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a well researched question here. In doing so, you've eliminated all of the "valid" solutions.

**You can definitely do what you have proposed**, which (harmlessly*) breaks the standards.  To be [future proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_proof), all HTML standards allow for unknown elements, instructing browsers to ignore them (essentially, they all become `<span>` elements) since there's no indication of what to do with them, though CSS can indeed affect them.  This will work in *ALL* browsers, even Mosaic and the original IE (though CSS won't work in such ancient browsers).

As you already noted, the "proper" way to do this would be to define your own [Document Type Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) (DTD) that can then be included at the top of your ~HTML document with the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.  This is probably overkill, but it is technically the right approach.

Another solution (that you've also eliminated) would be to use `<span class="HGroup">` for inline elements and `<div class="HGroup">` for block elements since these elements don't actually do anything by default.

A variant of that solution is to override the action of some otherwise useless tag and disable its standard properties in CSS, `<s>` for example:

```css
s {
  text-decoration: none; /* remove line-through */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

(* The "harm" you can run into with custom element names is that if you don't specify a DTD (your own or else an existing one with an exact version), a future version of the HTML standard could theoretically define some undesired property for your custom element.)

Answer (score 7):

Custom HTML elements are supported by HTML5, but according to [**the specs**](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) they should contain a `-` character :

> The name must contain a dash (-). So for example, `<x-tags>`,
>   `<my-element>`, and `<my-awesome-app>` are all valid names, while `<tabs>`
>   and `<foo_bar>` are not. This restriction allows the parser to
>   distinguish custom elements from regular elements but also ensures
>   forward compatibility when new tags are added to HTML.

See [**this article**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) for a good introduction.

Applying CSS to custom HTML elements works the same way as applying CSS to standard HTML elements :

```css
custom-element {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ff0;
}
```

```html
<custom-element>
    This is a custom HTML element
</custom-element>
```